# VIM regex capture group catches nothing

Tags: regex, vim, capture-group

I am parsing some files using vim and would like to change the format of the following code.

Original format:

```
vmm_note(log, "TEST_DIR - BEGIN");
```

Desired format:

```
uvm_info("Test_seq", "TEST_DIR - BEGIN",UVM_LOW);
```

When this code is only one line, the following regex is functioning.

```
%s/vmm_note(log,\(.*\));/uvm_info("Test_seq",\1,UVM_LOW);/gc
```

However, when the code consists of multiple lines, my regex can match the pattern but in the replacement, group `\1` contains nothing.

Original format:

```
vmm_note(log, $psprintf("INFO: setting debug port to watch %0s",
                    (req_info.debug_which==4'd0) ? "MC" :
                     "LZHI"));
```

Regex:

```
%s/vmm_note(log,\(\_.\)\{-};/uvm_info("Test_seq",\1,UVM_LOW);/g
```

Result:

```
uvm_info("Test_seq",),UVM_LOW);
```

I wonder why the capture group doesn't contain anything in it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What's the desired output for the second "original format"?

Comment: uvm_info("Test_seq", $psprintf("INFO: setting debug port to watch %0s",     
                    (req_info.debug_which==4'd0) ? "MC" :                   
                     "LZHI"),UVM_LOW);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, instead of `\(\_.\)\{-};` use `\(\_.\{-}\);` to include the desired text in the capturing group. So the multi-line substitution becomes:

```
%s/vmm_note(log,\(\_.\{-}\);/umv_info("Test_seq",\1,UVM_LOW);/g
```

Sample input:

```
vmm_note(log, $psprintf("INFO: setting debug port to watch %0s",            
                       (req_info.debug_which==4'd0) ? "MC" :                   
                        "LZHI"));
```

output:

```
umv_info("Test_seq", $psprintf("INFO: setting debug port to watch %0s",     
                    (req_info.debug_which==4'd0) ? "MC" :                   
                     "LZHI"),UVM_LOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
%s/vmm_note(log,\(\_[^;]*\));/uvm_info("Test_seq",\1,UVM_LOW);/gc
```

hope this helps,